# how to lookup the associated file with the given namespace?

Tags: clojure

I want to be able to write a function `lookup-file` where I pass a namespace and it will be able to automatically resolve the `.clj` file.

ie:

```
(lookup-file 'rabbit.warren-test)
;=> "test/rabbit/warren-test.clj"

(lookup-file 'rabbit.warren)
;=> "src/rabbit/warren.clj"

(lookup-file 'clojure.core)
;=> "~/.m2/repositories/org/clojure/clojure/clojure-1.9.0.jar:/...."
```

Is there a built-in function that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get some information by using this trick:

```
(defn files-for-ns [ns-sym]
  (->> (ns-publics ns-sym) 
       keys
       (map resolve)
       (map meta)
       (map :file)
       set))
```

or if you wanted the full paths:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(defn files-for-ns [ns-sym]
  (->> (ns-publics ns-sym) 
       keys
       (map resolve)
       (map meta)
       (map :file)
       set
       (keep identity)
       (map io/resource)
       (map str)))
```

Example:

```
(use 'clojure.pprint)
(pprint (files-for-ns 'clojure.core))
("jar:file:/Users/Borkdude/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.9.0-alpha10/clojure-1.9.0-alpha10.jar!/clojure/gvec.clj"
 "jar:file:/Users/Borkdude/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.9.0-alpha10/clojure-1.9.0-alpha10.jar!/clojure/core_proxy.clj"
 "jar:file:/Users/Borkdude/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.9.0-alpha10/clojure-1.9.0-alpha10.jar!/clojure/core.clj"
 "jar:file:/Users/Borkdude/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.9.0-alpha10/clojure-1.9.0-alpha10.jar!/clojure/core_print.clj"
 "jar:file:/Users/Borkdude/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.9.0-alpha10/clojure-1.9.0-alpha10.jar!/clojure/core_deftype.clj"
 "jar:file:/Users/Borkdude/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.9.0-alpha10/clojure-1.9.0-alpha10.jar!/clojure/genclass.clj")
```

Comment: that's kinda what I'm looking for... but you know how when we load a namespace and the file is spelt incorrectly... there is an exception that says... sorry x/y/z.clj is missing

Comment: so not the files that have already been loaded, but the files that are about to be loaded.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not entirely clear to me what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

No. Not only is there no built-in function, this is not even a thing that is knowable in general, since a given namespace may be defined in zero or more files. clojure.core, for example, is defined in many source files, and by defining a namespace just in your repl, you can create namespaces with no corresponding source file at all.

Comment: maybe clojure.core was a bad example. in general, there is one file per namespace. somehow emacs knows where to look when I eval a file